# Android Bluetooth LE push notifications

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been working with iOS ANCS BLE notifications, it works great because our BLE accessory can receive app notifications 'out of the box' without installing our own app on the Apple device.

I'm newer to the Android development environment. Is there an equivalent for Android or does an Android app need to be running to push notifications over BLE. If an app is required is there a GATT standard I should be following similar to ANCS ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with IOS ANCS as well, and like you mentioned it works very well without the need of installing an app on the app device. But Android does not provide something similar to this. You will need to write your own app and install it on the android device.

Its good to point out that IOS does not give you access to notifications but android does, which is why it its possible to write your own app.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap you can use ANCS for android just add service UUID and Characteristics UUID your app and add characteristic in GATT service.Than callback